# Map in F# auto sorts but I don't know why

Tags: f#

So when I do something like this

```
let mainMenu() = ["1. list item one",itemOne
                  "2. list item two",itemTwo
                  "3. list item three",itemThree
                  "4. list item four",itemFour
                  "0. Exit",exitApplication] 
                  |> Map.ofList
```

and print it like this

```
mainMenu() 
|> Seq.iter(fun keyValuePair -> 
    Console.WriteLine (sprintf "%s" (keyValuePair.Key |> string)))
```

I get a result of

```
0. Exit
1. list item one
2. list item two
3. list item three
4. list item four
```

So my question is, how does it know to put 0 first in the list?

My assumption is that it's hashing the char 0 and that it's getting put into a bucket earlier on since it's ascii value is lower

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F#'s `Map`s are implemented using binary search trees (specifically AVL trees, I believe), not hash maps. Iterating a binary search tree depth-first gives you the items in sorted order.

Comment: Oh okay yeah that would make sense too.

Comment: Note that this is not an implementation detail - it's part of the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.map['key,'value]-class-[fsharp]) of the class: "Immutable maps. Keys are ordered by F# generic comparison."